# "Worth of an" or "worth as an"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I am having trouble deciding the correct phrase. Which of these two is correct?

> Is gold worth as an investment?

Or

> Is gold worth of an investment?

Answer (score 1):

Both are incorrect.

Correct version is

`Is gold worth an investment?`

Check [this.](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/62598-worth-usage)

Answer (score 1):

1. > Is gold worth an investment?

   - Does gold have the worthiness and desired returns for us/anyone to invest in?
2. > Is gold worth as an investment?

   - I know gold has worth. But what about as an investment?
3. > Is gold worth of an investment?

   - I think investments are silly. Does gold have the worth of investments?
   - I think investments are very essential. Does gold have the worth of investments?
4. > Is gold worthy as an investment?

   - Gold is worthy, but is it still worthy if it is an investment?
   - Gold may be worthless for salvation, but is it worthy if it is an investment?
5. > Is gold worthy of an investment?

   - *another way of saying (1)*.